# Is it possible to share cookies between two different apps?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session-cookies, cookiestore

I have two separate apps ( that still share the same database ), in which one is a beta experience. I was curious if it was possible using cookie_store to share session data between them. Since the database is connected, possibly I could use that?

For example, how can I share session cookie data to the other app if they were to switch between apps, yet still stay logged in?

Comment: The two different apps, do they share the same domain (use subdomains). Or are they hosted in separate domains?